# How to display a screen if there is No Internet Connection ? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display some error scenarios if there is no internet available. If I'm going to the screen, disable the internet connection, coming back again, it shows me the `ErrorScreen()` case, but if I'm enabling the internet again, press try again button, it always showing me the No Internet Screen. I've been debugging it and `viewModel.networkMonitor.isConnected` is false, but the internet connection is on. I need to restart the app to show me the screen again.

**What my app does** : Enter the PersonalDataScreen, the screen is shown, disable internet, go again to the screen, it showing me the ErrorScreen for No Internet connection, enable the internet again, going back, keep showing me the same screen ( No Internet Screen ) .

**What my app needs to do** : When enable the internet again and I'm pressing on the button from the screen, to show me the `UserProfileScreen()` again. The same problem is with  the second error scenario `viewModel.presentingUnknownError`.

This is the Screen :

```
struct PersonalDataScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PersonalDataViewModel
    @Injected private var config: PersonalDataJourney.Configuration
 
    init(viewModel: PersonalDataViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        viewModel.fetchUserProfileData()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let strings = config.strings
        VStack {
            if viewModel.presentingLoader {
                LoaderView()
            } else {
                if !viewModel.networkMonitor.isConnected {
                    ErrorScreen(title: strings.noInternetTitle, subtitle: strings.noInternetDescription, button: strings.errorButton) {
                        viewModel.fetchUserProfileData()
                    }
                }
                else if viewModel.presentingUnknownError {
                    ErrorScreen(title: strings.techicalErrorTitle, subtitle: strings.technicalErrorDescription, button: strings.errorButton) {
                        viewModel.fetchUserProfileData()
                    }
                }
                else {
                  UserProfileScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel :

```
class PersonalDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Injected private var personalDataUseCase: PersonalDataUseCaseProtocol
    @ObservedObject public var networkMonitor = NetworkMonitor.shared
    @Published var personalDataAssetsData: PersonalDataAssetsData?
    @Published var presentingLoader = false
    @Published var presentingUnknownError = false
    
    func fetchUserProfileData() {
        presentingLoader = true
        personalDataUseCase.performPersonalDataRequest { [weak self] result in
            self?.presentingLoader = false
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                self?.personalDataAssetsData = response
            case .failure:
                self?.presentingUnknownError = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the NetworkMonitor class :

```
class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    @Published var isConnected = true
    static let shared: NetworkMonitor = {
        NetworkMonitor()
    }()

    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `NetworkMonitor` object have to be inside `PersonalDataViewModel`? have you tried to pass it as an environmental value to `PersonalDataScreen`?

Answer (score 0):

`@ObservedObject` can only be used in View. `networkMonitor` in the VM is not wrapped with `@Published` -> view doesn't listen to it at all. 
What you can do is to declare a `@Published var isConnected: Bool` in the VM, listen to the Publisher `$networkMonitor.isConnected` (@Published has a built-in publisher) and update the `isConnected` in VM